# Why can't I make an int array using 'const int*' same as 'const char*'?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, literals

Why can I create a string or array of chars in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  const char *string = "Hello, World!";
  std::cout << string[1] << std::endl;
}
```

? and it outputs the second element correctly, while I can't make an array of integer type without the array's subscript notation `[ ]`? What's the difference between the char's one and this one: `const int* intArray={3,54,12,53};`.

Comment: You can do it in C that supports compound literals. C++ does not support compound literals. For example const int* intArray= ( int[] ){3,54,12,53};.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Note that the C compound literals differ from the string literal case in a couple notable ways: 1) They're default mutable unless explicitly `const` qualified, e.g. `( const int[] ){3,54,12,53}` (string literals aren't `const` in C, but modifying them is undefined behavior; they're effectively `const`) 2) String literals always have static storage duration no matter where they're declared. Compound literals have static storage duration only in global scope. At function scope, they're automatic storage duration; they disappear when you return, so no returning pointers to 'em.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "why" is: "Because string literals are special". The string literal is stored in the binary, as a constant part of the program itself, and `const char *string = "Hello, World!";` is just treating the literal as an anonymous array stored elsewhere which it then stores a pointer to in `string`.

There is no equivalent special behavior for other types, but you can get the same basic solution by making a named static constant and using that to initialize the pointer, e.g.

```
int main() {
  static const int intstatic[] = {3,54,12,53};
  const int *intptr = intstatic;
  std::cout << intptr[1] << std::endl;
}
```

The effect of the `static const` array is to allocate the same constant space the string literal would use (though unlike string literals, it's less likely that the compiler will identify duplicate arrays and coalesce the storage), but as a named variable rather than an anonymous one. The string case could be made explicit in the same way:

```
int main() {
  static const char hellostatic[] = "Hello, World!";
  const char *string = hellostatic;
  std::cout << string[1] << std::endl;
}
```

but using the literal directly makes things a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature exists in C and is named **compound literal**.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int *intArray = ( int[] ){ 3, 54, 12, 53 };

    printf( "%d\n", intArray[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

However C++ does not support this feature from C.

There is a difference compared with string literals. String literals have static storage duration independent on where they appear while compound literals have either static storage duration or automatic storage duration dependent on where they are appear.

In C++ something that is close to this feature is `std::initializer_list` . For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int main() 
{
    const auto &myArray = { 3, 54, 12, 53 };

    std::cout << myArray.begin()[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *almost* can. There are a couple of things at work.

`{1,2,3}` and `"abc"` are not the same thing. In fact, if you wanted to draw a comparison, `"abc"` should rather be compared to `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`. Both of them are valid array initializers:

```
char foo[] = "abc";
char bar[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

However, only `"abc"` is also a valid expression to initialize a pointer in C++.

In C (and as an extension in some C++ compilers, including Clang and GCC), you can cast compound literals to an array type, like this:

```
static const int* array = (const int[]){1, 2, 3};
```

However, this is almost never correct. It works at the global scope and as a function argument, but if you try to initialize a variable of automatic storage with it (i.e. a variable within a function), you'll get a pointer to a location that is about to expire, so you won't be able to use it for anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The strings litterals come from the C language. Any string declared with double quotes in the code is automatically converted as a const char[].

So this:

```
const char str[6] = "hello";
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
const char str[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the specialness though: `const char *str = "hello";` is special and legal; it creates a pointer to an anonymous, constant character array that exists for the whole of the program's lifetime. You can't get a behavior like that from arbitrary array types (even `char` array initializers don't benefit from the magic applied to string literals).

Comment: If I remember you can do tricky stuff in C such as `const int *ptr = (const int[3]){0, 21, 42};` , am I wrong?

Comment: Well, one, this is a C++ question, and the C++ standard doesn't allow that, and two, as others have noted in their answers, it's subtly different when done at function scope; the lifetime of the anonymous array ends when the function returns, so the pointer can't be returned and used without invoking undefined behavior (it's pointing to "dead" memory). A string literal points to static storage, whether it's used at function or global scope, but the anonymous array syntax has varying storage type.